# SWIFT: Passing variable from closure to function

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to create a function which returns an NSDictionary, which on its turn needs to be returned from a closure.

I'm relatively new to Swift and I'm having problems figuring this one out.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Takes a String, needs to return a NSDictionary

func login(action: String) -> NSDictionary 
{
    let command = NSURL(string: "\(connectionType)://\(url)/includes/api.php?username=\(username)&password=\(password)&accesskey=\(apiKey)&action=\(action)&responsetype=json")
    print(command!)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    // Get error here when changing Void > NSDictionary
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(command!) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in 

        if error != nil {

            print(error!.localizedDescription)

        } else {

            do {
                let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                print(result) // Need this returned

            } catch {
                // handle error
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()

    return result As! NSDictionary // returns empty, because of -> Void??

}
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is impossible. `result` doesn't exist yet because it hasn't been created yet. `NSURLSession` will take a while to download the JSON data (it could take minutes) and only after that will you be able to access the result value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `dataTaskWithURL` is an asynchronous function, therefore it hasnt got around to executing the block yet before it returns the function.

what you need to do is either setup a function that can be called on `self` that will let `self` know when the block has executed and can pass you the result, or setup a protocol with a delegate that you can call to notify of the result

also, the `-> Void` inside the block is the return type of the block, you shouldnt really be returning anything inside that block anyway because nothing will actually happen with it since the parent function doesnt expect anything to be returned, hence why its `Void`

Answer (score 2):

In your declaration of the closure's type

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(command!) {
    (data, response, error) -> Void in
    /* closure body */
}
```

change the `Void` to `JSONObject`. But that's not all! You're trying to return something from a login function that makes an asynchronous call, and that's impossible. Instead, your `login` function itself needs to take a closure, and that closure will be where you do something with the result `NSDictionary`. So change your declaration of `login` to

```
func login(action: String, completionHandler: (NSDictionary) -> ())
```

and implement the `completionHandler` accordingly.

Comment: The first part of your answer won't work.  The method `dataTaskWithURL` expects the completion handler to return `Void` and trying to change it will just cause a compiler error.